# eclipse php xdebug doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: php, eclipse

Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: 3.2.0

php5.4.12 (wamp)

I'm using php eclipse xdebug for a few years now - sometime the xdebug doesn't break.

I notice that it happen mostly on ajax calls, and I found that one cause is that the previous debug session didn't end.

But now I'm debugging an ajax call,
I'm using the chrome devtool and I do 'replay XHR' to run the exact same ajax call, and it doesn't break 2 out of every 3 runs.

This is a great waste of time for me and I would appreciate any idea of how to overcome it, including a suggestion for a different (and better debugger)

Note:

- upgrading the php is not an option because I must use the same version as the production sev.
- I also tried upgrading the eclipse - but it causes to many (other) issues

Comment: I dont know much about Eclipse, but I have overcome a similar one with PhpStorm by adjusting a setting for debug (number of maximum connections) ... now up to 20 for some specific test runs.

Answer (score 1):

- In eclipse->preferences->PHP->Debug->Installed debuggers
- choose Xdegbug, and click `configure`
- check the `Use Multisession` checkbox
- click `ok`

This will cause xdebug to break even when a session is already running - but it can be a pain when submiting multiple requests.